# C# Error: 'ExtentReports' is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

Getting error while typing public ExtentReports ext

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;

using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;


namespace TestProject1.BaseClass
{
[TestFixture]
public class BaseTest
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public ExtentReports ext; //shows error here
}
}
```

also tried :
using AventStack.ExtentReports;

Comment: What is the error? Missing namespace? Mark the line and see if you get suggestions for adding namespace? Also make sure it is clear what the error is in question you ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a red squiggly line that appears on ExtentReports for the code line : public ExtentReports ext; with a suggestion stating : 'ExtentReports' is a namespace but is used like a type

Comment: Read the documentation and see what the name of the type you want to use actually is. Maybe it should be `ExtentReport` rather than `ExtentReports`.

Comment: ok i have tried downloading ExtentReports 5.0.2 and its now not throwing any error ..